# Error while installing flutter in windows10

Tags: android, flutter

I have tried to install flutter many times but it is showing error in installing it.

[image: image showing error while installation]

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.1)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.

```
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

[!] Connected devices

```
! No devices available
```

Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: I think you need to install it manually in IntelliJ preferences under `Plugins` install the plugins "Dart", and "Flutter".

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The "No devices available" message will go once you connect a device with developer/debug mode on.

2) Steps to install Flutter plugin.

- Open the Settings dialog(File->Settings)
- In the left-hand pane, select Plugins.
- On the Plugins page that opens in the right-hand part of the dialog, click the Install JetBrains plugin or the Browse repositories button.
- In the dialog that opens, search for Flutter.
- Right-click on Flutter and select Download and Install.

Answer (score 1):

Visit official Source for updated instructions: https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/

Flutter is supported by two plugins: Install the Flutter and Dart plugins

The Flutter plugin powers Flutter developer workflows (running, debugging, hot reload, etc.). The Dart plugin offers code analysis (code validation as you type, code completion, etc.).
To install these:

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Open plugin preferences (Preferences>Plugins on macOS, File>Settings>Plugins on Windows & Linux).
3. Select Browse repositories…, select the Flutter plug-in and click install.
4. Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
5. Click Restart when prompted.

[image: Flutter-Dart plugin installation screenshot]

Note: First follow the install instructions on https://flutter.io